# How to choose a set of parameters to guarantee the stability of a square matrix?

Tags: matrices, control-theory, linear-control

Suppose a square matrix $A$ is dependent upon a set of parameters $\left\{ \lambda _1, \lambda _2, \dots, \lambda _n \right\}$. By changing the $\lambda_i$'s, we can make the eigenvalues of $A$ lie in the left-half of $s$-plane.

Is there some quick method (instead of exhaustive search) to get a feasible $\lambda$?

Comment: Depends on the how $A$ depends on $\lambda$. For example when it is a discontinuous function it will probably be very unlikely that there will be a quick method.

Comment: Why not use the Lyapunov equation?

Comment: The question in the title doesn't match the one in the post, so which one is the question?